# How to only declare a function in one crate and define/implement it in an other crate in Rust?

Tags: rust, forward-declaration

I want to make a function to load a texture from file.
The texture struct itself is in the crate "common".
I want a function "load" which is declared in "common" but
implemented in "graphics" - since it requires access to graphics API.
In C++ I just could have forward declared that function...
I've found this but is there a better way instead of extern "C"?
https://users.rust-lang.org/t/call-function-declared-in-crate-but-defined-in-other-crate/23598

Thanks in advance!

Comment: define a `Loadable` trait with a `load()` function in the graphics portion and implement it for your texture class?